# Is there an outer product counterpart for the Covariance?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation, covariance, intuition, linear-algebra

###### Covariance

The covariance of two quantities $X$ and $Y$ within a population, $Cov(X,Y)$, is symmetric and bilinear. It is also true that $Cov(X,X) \ge 0$. So, clearly $Cov(X,Y)$ qualifies as an inner product, and it measures how much the two quantities vary *with* each other. My question is whether or not there is some counterpart to $Cov(X,Y)$ which measures how much the two quantities vary *independently* of each other, which might be called an "outer" product?

###### What would such a product look like?

I would expect the product to be maximized when $Cov(X,Y) = 0$ in which case all the variance from both variables would be included, maybe something like $\sigma(X)\sigma(Y)$, but the product of $X$ with itself should be $0$.

So my first guess for how this product would be defined would be something like:
$$
\sigma(X)\sigma(Y - X\dfrac {Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma(X)^2})
$$

If that makes sense (tell me if it doesn't), then it satisfies the conditions above. Does such a product exist in statistics? And if it does, is it actually useful?

Comment: In correlation terms you might think about $1-\rho^2$, so scaling this up you might think about $\sigma^2(X) \sigma^2(Y) -Cov(X,Y)^2$.  If that is in the wrong units, you might take the square root.

Comment: Well, certainly just doing $\sigma(X)\sigma(Y) - Cov(X,Y)$ is much simpler than my formula and satisfies my conditions as well. It also has a pretty clear interpretation. You just take away the portions of the variance that vary together, and that gives you the parts that vary independently. I wonder if they are actually equivalent..

Comment: $\sigma(X)\sigma(Y) - Cov(X,Y)$ does not meet your "maximized when $Cov(X,Y)=0$" requirement: it is possible to have  $Cov(X,Y)=-\sigma(X)\sigma(Y)$ and so $\sigma(X)\sigma(Y) - Cov(X,Y) = 2 \sigma(X)\sigma(Y) $

Comment: Good point.
I've been doing some algebra and I think I've proved that my original formula is in fact the square root of yours, so it's nice to know there is a simple formula for this.
Let's start by calling $\dfrac {Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma(X)^2} = \lambda$, then looking at $\sigma(Y - \lambda X)^2 = \sigma(Y)^2 + \sigma(\lambda X)^2 - 2Cov(Y, \lambda X) = \sigma(Y)^2 + \lambda^2 \sigma(X)^2 - 2 \lambda Cov(X, Y)$

Comment: Now, expanding out the $\lambda$s gives $\sigma(Y - \lambda X)^2 = \sigma(Y)^2+ \dfrac {Cov(X,Y)^2} {\sigma(X)^2} - 2 \dfrac {Cov(X, Y)^2} {\sigma(X)^2} = \sigma(Y)^2 - \dfrac {Cov(X,Y)^2} {\sigma(X)^2}$

Multiply both sides by $\sigma(X)^2$, and the proof is done.

Comment: Man, I was trying to figure out why that formula looked so familiar. It's been killing me, but I finally figured it out: It's Lagrange's Identity!
Which states that $|\vec{x} \times \vec{y}|^2 = |\vec{x}|^2|\vec{y}|^2 - (\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y})^2$
Awesome!